# php allow submit if variable is true

Tags: php, submit

Newbie here, and self-taught in PHP. I have a questionnaire where each question has 2 answers, and users can add any combination of numbers to each, as long as they equal, i.e. 10. So far 2 questions (will be more) so each question's answers should equal 10, therefore total submitted values should equal 20. I can't find a way to only allow submit if these conditions are met. I would really appreciate any help.

Currently using this for testing purposes:

```
<input type="submit" value="Check!" name="check"/>
```

...at the bottom.

```
<?php
// Start the session
session_start();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<?php
// Adding stuff

if(isset($_POST['check']))
{
$q1total=$realist[1]+$idealist[1];
$q2total=$realist[2]+$idealist[2];
$grandtotal=$q1total+$q2total;
}
?>

<body>
<form method="post">
Q1: <input type="text" name="realist[1]"/> <input type="text" name="idealist[1]"/>
<?php echo $q1total; ?>
<br>

Q2: <input type="text" name="realist[2]"/> <input type="text" name="idealist[2]"/>
<?php echo $q2total; ?>
<br>

<br><br>
Grand total: <?php echo $grandtotal; ?>
<br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Check!" name="check"/>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `if $grandtotal == 20` ?

Comment: Thanks B001 - that's what I'm playing with but not sure how to write that section of code. Can you advise please?

Comment: where are you submiting this answers to?

Comment: Are you getting the values `after` submitting check?

Comment: Nowhere yet, working on the form page first. It will be to another page displaying results + emailing results + writing to csv. Comfortable with those other bits, it's just this which is puzzling me.

Comment: I was thinking to have 2 buttons - a first one for the user to check the totals, then a second to submit if all is correct.

Comment: I will ask you to go for jQuery to do so along with php too

Comment: I would suggest that when the form is submitted you run a javascript function that will do the validation and check if your condition is met then submit

Comment: Thanks for your input. Javascript/jQuery is a little beyond me - do you know of a copy-and-paste of this I could use, please?

Answer (score 0):

I'm also a self-taught PHP "newbie" as you describe it. I would honestly create a seperate PHP file that checks if the conditions are met.

Your form would be:

```
<form method="post" action="yourfile.php">
```

And in the php file:

```
      $realist1 = $_POST["realist\[1\]"]; 
        $idealist1 = $_POST["idealist\[1\]"];
        $realist2 = $_POST["realist\[2\]"];
        $idealist2 = $_POST["idealist\[2\]"];


    if ($realist[1]+idealist[1]== 10 && $realist[2]+idealist[2] == 10)
    {
      echo "<button value='correct'/>";
    }else{
      echo "<button value='incorrect' disabled/>";
    }
```

Obviously you have to adjust some stuff but hopefully this can help.